# Tomcat log files not found error

Tags: tomcat

At my new workplace, I run into some log file not found errors on newly installed Tomcat. Those Tomcat log files are catalina..log, localhost_access_log..txt and so on. Those Tomcat log files are not in under /logs. The problem occurs on both Tomcat 9 and Tomcat 8 on Windows 7. Does a Windows access restriction cause the problem?

Comment: Maybe. How are you starting Tomcat?

Comment: You are on a right spot.

Answer (score 0):

I find that the problem indeed has something to do with how to start TC. If I start TC from the Windows service panel, the problem won't occur.